# Force Installing a Radeon HD 2100 on Windows 8

Tags: installation, windows-8-preview, amd-radeon

I'm trying force installing a Radeon HD 2100 on Windows 8.

I've found that link from AMD with the drivers for Windows7:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeonaiw-vista64.aspx

I know too that AMD will stop support Radeon HD 400 and older:
http://www.techspot.com/news/48321-amd-drops-windows-8-support-for-radeon-hd-4000-and-older.html

Now, let's go to the problem. If I try install the 12.6 driver, Windows will stick with the  "basic display adapter", and this is bad for 3d games like Minecraft, that runs really slow now compared with the previous Windows7 installation.

Forcing install the catalyst driver can help to fix it. So, I follow that steps:

1. Extract the Catalist Driver (C:\AMD\Support\12-6-legacy_vista_win7_64_dd_ccc_whql)
2. Right click the "basic display adapter" on device manager, and "update driver"
3. Search on PC
4. I will choose the driver
5. "With Disk"
6. "C:\AMD\Support\12-6-legacy_vista_win7_64_dd_ccc_whql\Packages\Drivers\Display\W76A_INF"
7. There is a big list of drivers and the nearest driver to HD 2100 is "Radeon HD 2350 Series"

My questions:

1. **Why isn't "Radeon HD 2100 Series" listed? (or Where is it listed?)**
2. In theory it must be listed" The first link above show that "This article applies to the following configuration(s):" (...) "AMD Radeon HD 2000 Series"
3. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does their website state that Windows 8 is supported for this card? If not, you're pretty much on your own. As I understand it, Windows 8 makes extensive use of hardware acceleration and your card may just not fit the bill.

Comment: @RandolphWest I understand you, but my question is about the fact of the card is not listed. The HD 4000 series and older aren't supported by Windows 8, but are listed, then it isn't the problem...

Comment: Maybe your theory is wrong. 2350 is still in the 2000 range, and you may just have a card that's too old.

Comment: @RandolphWest In the download page says "AMD Radeon HD 2000 Series", and if you go to product drive selector, it will get to this page too.

Comment: You should never have to force anything, just be gentle with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I manage to install.

I searched on my old folders on previous Win7 drivers and I found it.

The driver is named "10-02_legacy_vista32-64_dd_ccc".

Comment: Hello, `Click OK` How you solve the problem? I am facing exactly same problem. Please answer briefly. It will be useful to me and other having same card. Thank you.

Comment: @MadanSapkota Follow exactly the same steps from my question, but use the EXACTLY the file "10-02_legacy_vista32-64_dd_ccc" (google for it) instead of any alternative, so will appear Radeon HD 2100 in the list. WHY its happen I dont know...