# Graphic driver not supported in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Few days back I installed Windows 8 Pro(32 bit) earlier it was Win7 (32bit). My Desktop configuration is the image I uploaded.

The problem is Win8 not detecting my Graphic / Video Card. I didn't purchase any graphic cards myself but I hope the graphic card is built in with AMD processors or Gigabyte Motherboard because it is working fine with Win XP, Win7.

I install Latest motherboard drivers of my Model (no effect), I installed the latest version of processors drivers of my Model (no effect). Also I tried with Legacy drivers from AMD (no effect).

Please check both images. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

I pasted dxdiag information here [DxDiag Information](http://pastebin.com/9M8rTxcZ).

---

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 11/29/2012, 11:53:26
       Machine name: MUSIC_BARI
   Operating System: Windows 8 Pro 32-bit (6.2, Build 9200) (9200.win8_rtm.120725-1247)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
       System Model: GA-MA74GMT-S2
               BIOS: Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG
          Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 250 Processor (2 CPUs), ~3.0GHz
             Memory: 6144MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3326MB RAM
          Page File: 960MB used, 5565MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.02.9200.16384 32bit Unicode

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: Microsoft Basic Display Adapter
       Manufacturer: (Standard display types)
          Chip type: ATI ATOMBIOS
           DAC type: (C) 1988-2005, ATI Technologies
        Device Type: Display-Only Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_796E&SUBSYS_D0001458&REV_00
     Display Memory: 256 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 0 MB
      Shared Memory: 256 MB
       Current Mode: 1024 x 768 (32 bit) (64Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: W1643
         Monitor Id: GSM3E88
        Native Mode: 1360 x 768(p) (60.015Hz)
        Output Type: Other
        Driver Name: 
Driver File Version:  ()
     Driver Version: 6.2.9200.16384
        DDI Version: 11.1
     Feature Levels: 11.1,11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.2
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: , 0 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: n/a
    WHQL Date Stamp: n/a
  Device Identifier: {D7B71AF4-43CC-11CF-B023-F003ADC2CB35}
          Vendor ID: 0x1414
          Device ID: 0x008C
          SubSys ID: 0x00000000
        Revision ID: 0x0000
 Driver Strong Name: display.inf:10809047d4324726:MSBDA:6.2.9200.16384:pci\cc_0300
     Rank Of Driver: 00FB2006
        Video Accel: 
        DXVA2 Modes:
```

Comment: Post your dxdiag log otherwise we can't help.

Comment: click on graphic and post the screenshot. Your AMD CPU doesn't have an included graphic unit.

Comment: run GPU-Z (http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and look which GPU you have.

ok, the dxdiag log shows VEN_1002&DEV_796E. This is an ATI/AMD Radeon HD 2100. So install the 12.6 latency driver: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalyst126legacyproducts.aspx

Comment: sorry wrong link: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalystlegacywin8.aspx

For your Dual Core CPU, a Radeon HD 7750 or 7770 should be the best card.

Comment: as @magicandre1981 mentions, you have a AMD Radeon 2100. Check http://superuser.com/questions/455704/force-installing-a-radeon-hd-2100-on-windows-8 to see how you can force install the drivers

Comment: the Radeon HD5450 is a DX 11 card, so the normal Catalyst driver would work http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst1211betadriver.aspx. If you want to do gaming, the card is too slow. In this case the 77xx would better.

Comment: @MadanSapkota - Pure the dxdiag log, it sees your video memory, so Windows 8 sees your graphic card and the drivers are installed.  Its very likely that the drivers that are meant for your card will never be updaed to support Windows 8 based on the age of your CPU.

Comment: @Madan Sapkota if you don't play games, the HD5450 might be ok.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. This is how is solved it: I was using a HP Pavillion notebook with AMD Radeon GPU.

PROBS:

- dxdiag showed display was working OK with all direct X Features enabled, BUT graphics adpter name was Microsoft Basic Display Adapter and only showed 256 MB graphics memory instead of the 2GB in my Radeon Graphics adapter.
- Device Manager showed display adapter 'working properly', but instead of 'AMD Radeon' as my adapter showed Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.
- GPU-Z AND CPU-Z were all showing Microsoft Basic Display Adapter as my display adaptor.
- The graphics drivers from HP.com dint work and graphics card was still not detected.

SOLUTION:

1. I checked my notebook Specs from HP.com website and found that my notebook had AMD Radeon HD 8650M/8670M Dual GPU (1 GB DDR3 dedicated). This was the only way since device manager, dxdiag, system info, CPU-Z and GPU-Z were all showing Microsoft Basic Display Adapter as my adapter name!!
2. I went to the amd site: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download , System: Notebook, Family: Radeon HD Series, Product: Radeon HD 8xxxM Series, OS: Windows 8
3. Download Driver
4. Install and finally worked.